# Set same screen background from current view in stack view

Tags: android, stackview

I have a stack view of 5 images. Now I want to set background same as image in top of stack view and the background should be change when swipe stack for next image. I tried to set from `setOnItemSelectedListener` but its not working in stack view.

and here is my code..

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static  String Tag= "MainActivity";

    StackView stackView;
    ImageView rlayout;
    Drawable d;
    ImageView imageView;
    Integer[]   images = {

            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.three,
            R.drawable.four,
            R.drawable.five
    };

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        stackView = (StackView)this.findViewById(R.id.stackview);
        stackView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        rlayout = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.dfs);
        stackView.setRotation(180);

        stackView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e(Tag, "current position: "+position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context contxt;


        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            contxt = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup
                parent) {
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
                        getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.item, null, false);
            }

            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(
                    R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
            imageView.setRotation(180);

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("image click", "IMAGE CLICK");
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("position", ""+position);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```